# Regular Expression - Java

Tags: java, regex

For the string value `"ABCD_12"` (including quotes), I would like to extract only the content and exclude out the double quotes i.e. `ABCD_12` . My code is:

```
private static void checkRegex()
{
    final Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile("\"([a-zA-Z_0-9])+\"");
    Matcher findMatches = stringPattern.matcher("\"ABC_12\"");
    if (findMatches.matches())
        System.out.println("Match found" + findMatches.group(0));
}
```

Now I have tried doing `findMatches.group(1);`, but that only returns the last character in the string (I did not understand why !).

How can I extract only the content leaving out the double quotes?

Comment: Please try to give questions specific titles - there are dozens of questions with this basic title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
Pattern.compile("\"([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\"");
```

OR

```
Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"");
```

Problem in your code is a misplaced `+` outside right parenthesis. **Which is causing capturing group to capture only 1 character** (since `+` is outside) and that's why you get only last character eventually.

Answer (score 1):

A nice simple (read: non-regex) way to do this is:

```
String myString = "\"ABC_12\"";
String myFilteredString = myString.replaceAll("\"", "");
System.out.println(myFilteredString);
```

gets you

```
ABC_12
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your pattern to this:

`final Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile("\"([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\"");`

Note that the `+` sign was moved inside the group, since you want the character repetition to be part of the group. In the code you posted, what you were actually searching for was a repetition of the group, which consisted in a single occurence of a single characters in `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

If your pattern is strictly any text in between double quotes, then you may be better off using substring:

```
String str = "\"ABC_12\"";
System.out.println(str.substring(1, str.lastIndexOf('\"')));
```

Assuming it is a bit more complex (double quotes in between a larger string), you can use the split() function in the Pattern class and use \" as your regex - this will split the string around the \" so you can easily extract the content you want

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"");
    // Split input with the pattern
    String[] result = 
             p.split(str);
    for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++)
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29